# If condition in lambda expression to change value in java

Tags: java, lambda

This is a code snippet that I want to modify.

```java
fullAlert.getSupportingData().forEach( data ->      
    dataMap.put(data.getKey(), data.getValue())
);
```

I want to check if `data.getValue()` does return **empty or null**.
If so then

```
dataMap.put(data.getKey(), data.getValue())
```

Else I want to replace backslashes

```
dataMap.put(data.getKey(), data.getValue().replace("\\","\\\\"))
```

I am new to lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean the ternary operator not a lambda expression. That makes sense based on what you ask for.

```
fullAlert.getSupportingData().forEach(data -> dataMap.put(data.getKey(), data.getValue() != null && !data.getValue().isEmpty()? data.getValue().replace("\\","\\\\") : data.getValue()));
```

Comment: Lambda is marked by `->`. But substitute a simple if by [ternary]() usually has impact on readability. `Optional` could ease both here: readability and empty/null checks

Comment: @hc_dev regarding the question however it was more probable that the OP wanted something like that instead of an If/Else statement. Most programmers would not need help to form an if/else statement. Now maybe he could not open the brackets on the body of the lambda function. Only OP knows what needs for real.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with if-statements? They work inside lambdas too.
You have to open/close a block using curly braces after the arrow:

```java
fullAlert.getSupportingData().forEach( data -> {
    String value = data.getValue(); // default
    if (value != null && !value.isBlank()) {
       value = value.replace("\\","\\\\")); // special
    }
    dataMap.put(data.getKey(), value); // always put into map
});
```